# Cleaning up the memory in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory, spark-streaming

We are using the spark streaming for processing and aggregating the events. 
The job reads the events from kafka topic, aggregates them and writes to another kafka topic. We are using mapWithState function for stateful streaming and we are checkpointing into s3. All the state gets removed over a time since we have set the timeout (quite a long session timeout).

As we have observed the memory is getting full over the period and job hangs (eventually fails). Is there a way to configure so states are not held up in memory.

Is there a way to clean up the state?

Comment: For the memory cleanup you should rely on garbage collection. The state will be held for as long as someone refers to it, so your best shots are either raising the memory to the amount needed for your job or optimizing it in a way that enables the GC to kick in and clean up everything.

Comment: Yes...I agree. What my doubt is, once the data is checkpointed why it is still in the memory. Why all the state obhects are in memory even no events recieved for that particular key. Is there a way to tell explicitly to remove and read from check point when event comes for the old state key

Comment: Hi did you find out the solution for this ? or anything we can do to rectify this ? @ 
Girish Bhat M thanks